# Optical table without holes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, control-engineering, optics, holes

Most optical tables have holes. Are there also optical tables without holes? Or do these things have a different name?

Comment: You could make this a lot clearer by providing a photo of an optical table with holes (and credit the image owners). Are you asking about "breadboard" tables with holes for lenses, mirrors, etc. or something else. If it doesn't have holes why would a sheet of glass or marble not be adquate?

Comment: In practice, when the holes are unwanted, I've seen labs just cover them with a sheet of plastic (or any other material)

Comment: optical tables btw aren't just about the holes. It's also the flatness, stiffness, and dimensional stability ..... "optical breadboards" on the other hand are just about the holes, though with their smaller size the other factors aren't so much in your face

Comment: If you have no holes you need something else to mount stuff. Without holes, that's just a surface plate.

Comment: The term “surface plate” is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [surface plate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_plate).